# Word for a person who increases the argument

Tags: word-request

What can I name a person who increases the argument between two people.

Can I call him as **catalyst** or is any other word available?

Comment: *catalyst* is the commonest I can think of. I've been using this for years!

Comment: A quarrelsome person. See some *[synonyms](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/quarrelsome)* -- argumentative, bellicose, confrontational, militant. These are all adjectives, however. I've found only one noun, *hell-raiser*, but I'm unsure in what contexts it is used. There might be other nouns.

Comment: quarrelsome is the one who himself/herself is annoying and tempted to start quarrel. Here, the OP is talking about someone who tempts **others** to argue and fight! @CopperKettle

Comment: @MaulikV - oh, the meaning is "between two **other** persons"? I would do a search for synonyms for "instigator" then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/60992/20120

Comment: Does *escalator* fit? Is the to "increase" an ongoing argument or to increase the frequency of arguments in general?

Comment: @shawnt00 In theory escalator might fit because the person is "escalating" the conflict, but I have never heard the noun escalator used to refer to a person - it's is either a moving stairway or a means of rising or descending by stages.

Comment: @ColleenV I don't know that it's common but I think the word has some more general usage: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escalator Either way I was just throwing it out there along with my question.

Comment: I was thinking this was the English forum when I offered *escalator* (and that only in passing.) While I don't think it's particularly mysterious I don't recommend it to a learner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, I think two words would work.

> [Instigator](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instigator) - *a ​person who ​causes something to ​happen, ​especially **something ​bad***

or

> Inflammatory person

As we use 'inflammatory remarks' to denote something that causes something bad, inflammatory person is the one who *causes* dispute by adding [fuel to the fire](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/add+fuel+to+the+fire)

Comment: +1 for 'inflammatory' remark. It may not the exact term everybody would understand but metaphorically, this is a good option. And, I think 'instigator' is the *closest* possible answer to this question.

Comment: @MaulikV don't agree about "instigator", which is specifically the _cause_ (with a connotation of being through action, not inaction) - but the question asks for one who increases the argument, not who starts it. "Inflammatory" is fine though.

Answer (score 4):

Best suggestion: **conflict escalator**.
Also acceptable: argument escalator.

The term for increasing an argument would be to "escalate" the argument.
Unfortunately the term "escalator" would normally be held to mean an actual "moving stairs" escalator, such as in a building with multiple floors, so it is awkward to try to describe this concept with a single word.

If an argument, or disagreement, between Amit and Shiva starts out with polite words, but then Amit begins insulting and cursing Shiva, one could say "Amit is the one who escalated the argument".  If you said "Amit was the escalator" it would most likely draw puzzled looks, as people try to figure out how Amit *used to be* moving stairs made of metal, but somewhere along the line changed into human form.

It would sound appropriate to label someone as a "conflict escalator".  For example, one might say, "His attorney is a conflict escalator" to describe an attorney who looks to instigate fights between the parties involved.  (Here, instigate means to start an argument, where there wasn't one before.)

The other available words mentioned thus far, catalyst, and instigator, are a bit too general to capture the sense of a back-and-forth argument.  A catalyst would be someone whose presence is required for the argument to occur, but does not necessarily participate in the argument, such as two men arguing over a whether the bartender's shirt is blue or purple.  The bartender (their shirt, to be precise) is the catalyst, but may not be involved in the argument, or even aware of it.  An instigator would be the person who *starts*, i.e., instigates the argument, such as by verbally attacking the other person. Opinions can differ on who really started the argument, but the term instigator means the one who started it.  The term "inflammatory person" is a general negative label of another person.  It is not a specific description of the behavior of escalating an argument.

The one who "escalates" the argument would normally refer to a person or party who is directly involved in the argument, rather than an outside agent like a catalyst.

Comment: No objections to the word, but it might be worth explaining that "escalator" alone normally refers to a moving staircase.

Comment: I believe that was covered in the answer, with mentions of "moving stairs".

Comment: Google nGrams returns no results for "conflict escalator" - it's not something I would ever think to use over "instigator". Even though it is theoretically OK and I would probably understand the intent behind "he is a conflict escalator", it would sound odd to me. Also, I am not the source of the DV - this is just commentary not a criticism.

Comment: The original question involves a scenario where an "argument", i.e., conflict, is already occurring, and one of the parties "increases", i.e., escalates the argument.  The other suggestions thus far do not capture the idea that there is already an existing argument.  This term would be very appropriate in discussing which attorney one should select to represent you in a dispute.  For example, family law attorney who has a reputation as a "conflict escalator" is likely to trigger what is known as a "high conflict divorce".

Comment: There is also the concept of a "high conflict personality", which could apply to a person who is continually instigating and escalating arguments and conflicts in their relationships with others.  This also is a general label rather than a specific description of a person's behavior in a specific argument.

Comment: The original question did not actually specify whether the "him who escalates an argument between two people" is or is not one of the two people arguing.   The term "conflict escalator" term would apply to either situation.  For example, an attorney representing one of the people might have many billable hours if the dispute goes to trial. If the two people settle out of court using a mediator, the attorney would receive less or even nothing. This attorney would have an incentive to increase the argument, i.e., act as a conflict escalator.

Answer (score 2):

*[Agitator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/agitator)* comes close and could work, although this is not the normal context for it...

...as well as [incendiary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/incendiary#incendiary__12), although, again, this is not commonly used in your context.

Answer (score 2):

*Stirrer* is a British usage. Depending on your audience perhaps *trouble stirrer* or *argument stirrer* would be clear enough and also appropriate.

*Troublemaker* might fit as well although that can encompass as lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, there is a ***Positive*** way to *fuel the fire*:

> DEVIL'S ADVOCATE
>
> noun
>
> 1.a person who expresses a contentious opinion in order to provoke debate or test the strength of the opposing arguments

An alternative definition, and more appropriate to a friendly debate is:

- Someone who takes the other side of the argument *purely for the sake
  of argument*.

The one who *stokes the flames* of an argument in a **less positive light** is an *Antagonist*:

> ANTAGONIST
>
> noun
>
> 1.a person who actively opposes or is hostile to someone or something; an adversary

Some good synonyms are:

1. obstreperous
2. truculent
3. vociferous

Answer (score 1):

For figurative speaking occasions:

accelerant   A substance that accelerates the development of a fire. 
                          
                  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accelerant 
                          
                  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_accelerant

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster says one who provokes is a **provocateur**.